# Script para primeira carga sqlite Xamarin Android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

Estou precisando criar um script de primeira carga para o nosso aplicativo, o problema e que temos dois campos BLOB na nossa tabela, ele esta muito grande com isso gostaria de ver a melhor forma para implementar essa primeira carga?

Comment: Não entendi o que você está tentando fazer. Poderia explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a carga de banco BLOB (provavelmente imagem certo?) eu aconselho trocar para string, setando um caminho desse arquivo dentro da plataforma.

Você implementa um método para buscar o caminho onde deve salvar esses dados e pronto. Não acho interessante salvar a imagem ou QUALQUER OUTRO ARQUIVO dentro do sqlite.

Caso o usuário delete o arquivo, você simplesmente baixa de novo :)

Mas caso insista em fazer dessa forma, o ideal é que você utilize de imagens pequenas e com baixa resolução (ou arquivos com poucos dados) e faça essa carga colocando direto o array de bytes dentro da sua classe/script.

Para ler um pouco mais de xamarin de uma olhada no nosso blog [Studyxnet](http://studyxnet.com.br) :)